# Bypass basic authentication for only frontend application

Tags: java, reactjs, spring-boot, spring-security, basic-authentication

I have a **frontend** application written in **React** and a **backend** application written in **SpringBoot**. I have implemented basic authentication in the backend application(for all endpoints) using Spring Security. So now a username and password are required to access every endpoint.

***Requirement*** :

1. I don't want to pass a username and password from the frontend application to access backend application endpoints so basically, I want to bypass basic authentication for my frontend application.
2. If someone wants to access any endpoint outside my frontend app for example Postman, RestTemplate, etc then a username and password are required.

For example -

*if the request is coming from [www.abc.com](http://www.abc.com) (frontend app URL) then* basic authentication should be bypassed *for all endpoints but if the request is coming from [www.xyz.com](http://www.xyz.com), Postman, RestTemplate, or any other client then basic authentication should not be bypassed.*

I know how to bypass authentication on a specific endpoint within the backend application but I don't know how to bypass authentication for the requester, I did research over the internet as well but not found something useful. Looking for working code to fulfill the requirement.

Answer (score 0):

If you use some kind of reverse proxy (e.g. nginx) to serve your frontend, you can set the basic authentication parameters there.

e.g.

```
 location / {
    ...
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;
    proxy_set_header Authorization "Basic TOKEN";
 }
```

where `TOKEN` = `base64(username:password)`

Comment: Thanks for the reply but I don't want to use any other service between frontend and backend